# Flow: Inference error in for-of loop

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a code this is trying to validate object with attributes *id* and _name for specified type. Attribute *id* should be a number and *name* should be a string as declared in *FooT* type.

```js
function number(value: mixed): number {
  if (typeof value === "number") return value
  throw new TypeError("number required")
}

function string(value: mixed): string {
  if (typeof value === "string") return value
  throw new TypeError("string required")
}

function objectOf(attrs, value) {
  const obj = {}
  for (const key of Object.keys(attrs)) {
    const typeFn = attrs[key]
    obj[key] = typeFn(value[key])
  }
  return obj
}

type FooT = {
  id: number,
  name: string
}

const fooT: FooT = objectOf(
  {
    id: number,
    name: string
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Foo"
  }
)
```

Running flow shows this error. For some reason inferred return type of *typeFn* is not correctly determined in `for-of` loop when accessing object attribute values dynamically.

```
Cannot assign objectOf(...) to fooT because:
 • string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property id.
 • number [3] is incompatible with string [4] in property name.

 [3]  3│ function number(value: mixed): number {
       :
 [1]  8│ function string(value: mixed): string {
       :
 [2] 22│   id: number,
 [4] 23│   name: string
     24│ }
     25│
     26│ const fooT: FooT = objectOf(
     27│   {
     28│     id: number,
     29│     name: string
     30│   },
     31│   {
     32│     id: 1,
     33│     name: "Foo"
     34│   }
     35│ )
     36│
```

Is this an issue with flow or am I missing something?

Comment: You overwrote `string` and `number` with your functions. So `FooT` doesn't understand what you mean anymore. You might just change those function names to `numberCheck` and `stringCheck` or something.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into [issue #935 Type of object value not inferred correctly in for-in loop](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/935). You should be able to use the [`suppress_comment`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#suppresscomment-regex-a-classtoc-idtoc-suppress-comment-regex-hreftoc-suppress-comment-regexa) config and just put `$FlowFixMe` in the code to tell Flow to ignore that.